# Maximum Independent Set using Maximal MIS

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, approximation-algorithms, randomized-algorithms

I want to use multiple runs of maximal independent set (Luby's algorithm) to find a lower bound on the size of **maximum** independent set.

Are there any bounds on the number of times the maximal algorithm has to be run to find the true maximum with a high probability ?

The graphs don't possess any special properties.

Comment: What do you know about the question?  In other words, what have you tried to answer your own question?

Comment: My knowledge of approximation algorithms is minimal..the problem that I am working on was proven to be reducible to Maximum independent set but the graphs are so huge that even O(n^2) is practically impossible. The question was more of a reference request so that I can read up on the related material.

Comment: move to cs.stackexchange.com?

Comment: but in short maximum ind. set. is very very hard to approximate in general: not approximable within a factor of $n^{1-\epsilon}$ for any constant $\epsilon$. so look hard for special properties of your graph..bounded degree for example?

Comment: Isn't it easy to show that you will need exponentially many iterations to find a maximum independent set, even if you study graphs of maximum degree 2?

Comment: You need at least O(n^2) just to read the input.

Answer (score 2):

If the graph is a clique (or a set of disconnected cliques), then Luby's algorithm succeeds on the first iteration.